# Scaling material texture to be 1pixel = 1 unit

Tags: unity

I have a mesh I use to render a sprite texture I set up in a material. This mesh is planar XY-aligned and stationary. It's vertexes are generated from a PolygonCollider.

The problem is that I'm using 1 PPU in the rest of my sprites, but the sprite rendered in the texture looks extremely small.

How can I make the scale of the texture's material, so the size of a pixel in the material is equal to 1 unit?

I can't just scale it, because I need it to be EXACTLY 1 unit.

Comment: Can you give us more details about your mesh? Is it stationary? Planar? Aligned to the world XY plane? If so, we can map the texture in worldspace easily enough. If several of the answers are "no," then we need to map between its UV space and world space, which is trickier, and depends on details of how you've set up its UVs. As an aside, 1PPU will tend to make your scene objects *very* large, larger than optimizations in the culling & physics systems might be optimized for, so if you can I'd recommend changing to a more conventional scale.

Comment: Updated the question with more info. Its the same mesh than this one: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/146440/reshapable-polygonsprite/146460#146460 I know the issues with working with 1PPU, but im not using physics right now. I might rescale everything later to work with 100PPU.

Comment: Haha, I'd suspected it might be. You're in luck, that script makes this easy, since the UVs are already measured in world units. :) Don't forget to include details like that in your question, as they can have a big impact on how we approach a solution, and can open up simpler options than are available in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As luck would have it, [the previous script I gave you](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/146460/39518) already assigns UVs so that 1 unit of texture space = 1 Unity scene unit. So as long as you're not scaling or twisting your object, and its pivot (local origin) is exactly on an integer coordinate, then the texture repeat grid and the Unity world space grid will already match.

So, all we need to do now is account for the number of pixels in our texture.

Here I've used a [texture that's 16 x 16 pixels](http://kenney.nl/assets/roguelike-modern-city). So at the default 1:1 material scale, when the full texture repeats once for each Unity scene unit of space, it maps to 16 pixels per unit. (standard cube added for reference)

[image: 16x16 tiling brick texture]

If we only want one pixel per unit, then we need to slow down our traversal of the texture space, so we stay on each pixel longer. Specifically, we want to cross only one sixteenth of a unit of texture space for each full unit we have now.

So we change the texture tiling parameters in the Material inspector to 1/16 = 0.0625

[image: Sample of the material Inspector with tiling x & y parameters set to 0.0625 each]

Now each texture pixel (texel) covers exactly one Unity scene unit (again, shown with standard 1x1 unit cubes to demonstrate the alignment)

[image: Texture mapped with 1 pixel per world unit]

Comment: Based DMGregory!