# Procedurally create a polygonal shape filled with texture in unity 2d

Tags: unity, 2d

I want to **procedurally** create a polygonal shape filled with texture in unity 2d (no 3d meshes). Something that looks like this: https://www.conceptdraw.com/How-To-Guide/picture/landscape-plan/Building-Plans-Landscape-Garden-Design-Elements-Roofs.png

As you can see roofs can be rectangles, but also any polygonal shapes.

- I have tried so far LineRenderer which outlines a shape but I see no way how to put a texture of the same shape into it.
- I have tried sprites as well but I could not find a way to procedurally generate them
- I saw an example of https://github.com/epezent/ShapeRenderer and https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/sprite-management/shapes2d-make-art-fast-62586
- Ultimately I want something like https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html for any polygonal shape

Can it be done in vanilla unity 2d? Or should I rely on 3rd party libraries and if so which one would fit best?

p.s. I will most likely overlay that object with PolygonCollider2d for physics

Comment: [We have a question about dynamically creating textured polygons here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146440/39518). The answer shows shaping the polygon in the editor, but you could use the same script (or similar method) and pass it a list of vertices you've chosen procedurally just as well.

Comment: @DMGregory that one is 3d mesh, my question is for 2d only

Comment: Hint: 2D sprites are actually drawn as 3D meshes anyway. ;)

Comment: Im aware of that ;) My question was more around unity engine best practices. I ended up doing mesh for now. I might change it to something else once I need to texture it better.

Answer (score 2):

[Sprite shapes](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/09/20/intro-to-2d-world-building-with-sprite-shape/)

They allow you to create adbitary polygons filled in with sprites. You can also make the edges different based on the angle.

They've been built into Unity for a a year or so.

Comment: This is all done in Unity via UI and not procedurally. Is there an example of creating sprites procedurally?

Comment: @Zepplock You can change the shapes procedurally https://forum.unity.com/threads/spriteshape-preview-package.522575/#post-3441363