# Generating a sprite using a list of points

Tags: unity, c#, sprites

I am trying to dynamically generate a sprite in Unity to visualize a list of points.

What I've got so far is creating a small Texture2D object and then trying to override the geometry:

```
static SpriteRenderer SpriteRendererFromPoints(SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer, List<Vector2> points) { 
    var texture = Texture2D.whiteTexture;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    Sprite sprite = spriteRenderer.sprite;
    sprite.OverrideGeometry(points.ToArray<Vector2>(), sprite.triangles);
    return spriteRenderer;
}
```

I am adding this SpriteRenderer and a PolygonCollider2D to my gameobject and the instantiate it like this:

```
    GameObject meshObject = new GameObject();

    PolygonCollider2D polygonCollider = meshObject.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    PolygonCollider2DFromPoints(polygonCollider, points);

    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = meshObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    SpriteRendererFromPoints(spriteRenderer, (from point in points select new Vector2(point.x, point.y)).ToList<Vector2>());
    Instantiate(meshObject);
```

It all runs fine but when running this, the sprite is nowhere to be seen:
[image: unity_points]

Any help as to what I'm missing here or alternative ways of accomplishing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're asking the sprite to already know what triangle indices to use: `sprite.OverrideGeometry(points.ToArray<Vector2>(), sprite.triangles);` - how exactly do you expect `sprite.triangles` to already contain the correct indices to use from an array of points it's never seen until this line?

Comment: You can see an [example of computing indices for rendering a polygon sprite in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/146460/39518)