# Polygon filling algorithm

Tags: unity, textures, algorithm, terrain

Share your methods or algorithms for painting areal objects, I will be very grateful.  I have points `List <Vector2>` or `List <Vector3>`, there are textures with different settings:

[image]

And I need to fill the area.

For example, I have 4 coordinates, I painted a square by clicking the button:
[image]

Comment: You could always use bubble filling or rasterization

Comment: @Natalo77 can I have a link or examples?I will be grateful

Comment: Are you looking to create a polygon from a set of points and apply this material to it? If so, [this past Q&A may have some useful leads for you](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146440/39518). If you need something different, can you edit your question to show some examples of your desired effect?

Comment: @DMGregory My widget is building a terrain. I know the points of the polygon. I need to generate points inside the polygon. To receive List<Vector2> .To later, relative to this list, paint over the polygon

Comment: It looks like you should **edit your question** to walk us through this feature step-by-step, with example diagrams.

Comment: @DMGregory I have an example. BUT he paints for a long time . http://theinstructionlimit.com/fast-uniform-poisson-disk-sampling-in-c