# LineRenderer with color fill?

Tags: unity, line-renderer

For an interactive I'm making I want to highlight areas of focus using a polygon that has a border and a fill color. I can draw the border with a `linerenderer` but then how do I add a fill color to it?

*Example custom olygon with border*

[image: custom polygon with border example]

**Question**

Using Unity3d how can I create a custom polygon with a transparent fill color similar to the image above ?

*Ideas*

My current thought is that I can either customize the bounds of the plane via code or I can write a custom shader and pass in the points I'm using for the linerenderer in which case I might as well do all the drawing in the shader - but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Did you consider just [making a mesh in code with the desired shape](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/146460/39518)?

Comment: @DMGregory Good suggestion as that will make things a bit simpler. If it's mesh-making vs shader building why would I choose one over the other? It seems like the performance of the shader would be much better and I don't think it would be that much more complicated to make. What do you think ?

Comment: I'd suggest trying it. I think you'll find the shader approach more complicated, but I'd be happy to be wrong.

Comment: I'm not much for assets but I'm so scrunched on time that I pulled down [Shapes](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/shapes-173167) - When I get some time I'll do an open-source tool that does this same effect and will post back.