# Generating tris for concave polygon 2D

Tags: 2d, algorithm, geometry, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I have an arbitrary array of points that describe vertices of the polygon 2D, they ar in order. To generate plane mesh for that, I need to generate tris. For something like circle/hexagon/square it is not an issue, just pick any single point as a end-point and draw/generate all tris towards it. However, with concave polygon or arbitrary concave shape I'm having trouble figuring it out:

[image: example]

I assume I need to find an angle that is >180, but what next? What if there are multiple of such angles?

Comment: [The Wikipedia article on polygon triangulation is quite comprehensive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation), showing both the "ear clipping" algorithm that's simple to code up but not as efficient for large polygons and does not handle holes, and the "monotone triangulation" method that has better big-O complexity, but is a bit hairier to code. Have you tried implementing either of these standard algorithms for this problem?

Comment: [I wrote a sample ear clipping implementation for this earlier answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/146460/39518), in case that's useful to you.

Comment: Yes, I did now. I assume when you mention `naive O(n^3) ear clipping approach`  you are talking about the logic to detect an `ear`. I need to compute a dozen or two polygons with average value of vertices 8, and I need to do it under 1-2 ms preferably. What other algos can I look into?

Comment: Additionaly, is there a very fast/dirty approximate way to just quickly detect if polygon is concave to discard it?

Comment: Did you try implementing and profiling it? With such a small number of such tiny polygons, I don't expect even the naive approach would exceed your time budget. The Wikipedia article linked above mentions that you can improve the runtime to O(n^2) by keeping convex and concave vertices in separate lists, if you want a speed-up without a large increase in code complexity. You can detect concavity in a linear scan by walking clockwise around the perimeter and checking if an edge ever turns to the left, relative to the previous edge. If it's all right turns/straightaways, it's convex.

Comment: `by keeping convex and concave vertices in separate lists` vertices of the SAME polygon separately? That sounds bizzare. How would I keep tabs on the order of vertices?

Comment: The great thing about this being a well-known named algorithm is that you don't have to wait for me or any other user to explain it to you: lots of people already have, and [you can find detailed explanations and sample code just by searching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22ear+clipping%22+convex+concave&ia=web). Please **edit your question** to show how you've tried applying this wealth of available information so far, and where specifically you've gotten stuck or need something that's not covered by the available documentation.